# findLoadedClass() returns null

Tags: java, jvm, internals

[According to the JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3), the class loader that initiates loading of a class is recorded as the *initiating class loader* by the JVM. Furthermore, according to the JavaDoc of [ClassLoader#findLoadedClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findLoadedClass(java.lang.String)) the method

> Returns the class with the given binary name **if this loader has been recorded by the Java virtual machine as an initiating loader** of a class with that binary name.

(emphasis mine)

Consider a simple class loader

```
class SimpleClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    void foo() {
        System.err.println(loadClass("foo.Bar"));
        System.err.println(findLoadedClass("foo.Bar"));
    }
}
```

Given that `foo.Bar` actually exists in the class path, `new SimpleClassLoader().foo()` prints

```
class foo.Bar
null
```

According to the reasons given above, `SimpleClassLoader` should be the initiating class loader and `findLoadedClass("foo.Bar")` should just return the successfully loaded class.

Now consider this second version:

```
class SimpleClassLoader2 extends ClassLoader {
    SimpleClassLoader2() {
        super(null); // disables delegation
    }
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) {
        try {
            byte[] b = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream("path/to/foo/Bar.class"));
            return defineClass("foo.Bar", b, 0, b.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    void foo() {
        System.err.println(loadClass("foo.Bar"));
        System.err.println(findLoadedClass("foo.Bar"));
    }
}
```

This makes `SimpleClassLoader2` both the initiating as well as the defining class loader of `foo.Bar`. Indeed, now `new SimpleClassLoader2().foo()` prints the desired

```
class foo.Bar
class foo.Bar
```

So either the documentation is wrong or I don't understand why `SimpleClassLoader` is not regarded as the initiating class loader of `foo.Bar`. Can someone please shed some light into this?

Comment: Which classloader are you inheriting from? I ask because in the first case of SimpleClassLoader I would expect a ClassNotFoundException (given findLoadedClass calls findClass but I am not sure).

Comment: It doesn't because loading delegates to the parent first. Were I to set the parent to null in the first version, you'd be correct.

Comment: The default implementation of findClass is throwing the exception tough, http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ClassLoader.java#ClassLoader.findClass%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @guido: The code is sound. You are confusing the parent class loader with the parent class. The parent class loader is the same as the system class loader if not explicitly given (as in the second example). Since `foo.Bar` exists in the class path, it can load the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some more tests and I'm fairly sure the spec is correctly implemented. My mistake was thinking that reflectively loading a class is the same as having it load as part of the resolution step. It makes sense: Both the spec and the JavaDoc mention "recording" of a class loader as the initiating class loader. If I call `loadClass()` myself, the VM has no way of knowing what class loader should be the initiating class loader, so the defining class loader trivially becomes the initiating class loader as well.

This can be demonstrated by having the loaded class trigger loading of another class (`foo.Baz`) as part of dependency resolution but have another class loader do the actual loading.*

<sub>*I'm pretty sure this is not correct behavior of a valid class loader. I just do it to illustrate a point.</sub>

Consider the following classes (they are all in package `foo`):

```
public class Bar {
    public Bar() {
        new Baz();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Baz {
}
```

My custom class loader is now slightly modified:

```
public class SimpleClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    static final String PATH = "/path/to/classes";

    public SimpleClassLoader() {
        // disable parent delegation
        super(null);
    }

    public void printLoadedClass(String name) throws Exception {
        Class<?> cls = findLoadedClass(name);
        System.err.println("findLoadedClass(" + name + ") = " + cls
                + ", has class loader " + cls.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (name.equals("foo.Baz")) {
            // don't want to be defining class loader of foo.Baz
            return getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(name);
        }
        // now we're loading foo.Bar
        try {
            byte[] b = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(PATH + "/foo/Bar.class"));
            return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
        } catch (ClassFormatError | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ClassNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

The test is straight forward:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SimpleClassLoader cl = new SimpleClassLoader();
    Class<?> cls = cl.loadClass("foo.Bar");
    cls.newInstance(); // this triggers resolution

    cl.printLoadedClass("foo.Bar");
    cl.printLoadedClass("foo.Baz");
}
```

Output is

```
findLoadedClass(foo.Bar) = class foo.Bar, has class loader foo.SimpleClassLoader@3a65724d
findLoadedClass(foo.Baz) = class foo.Baz, has class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1a2b2cf8
```

As can be seen: `SimpleClassLoader` initiates loading of and also defines `foo.Bar`. Creating the instance triggers resolution of `foo.Baz`. This time, definition of the class is delegated to the
system class loader so it becomes the defining class loader. The output shows that `SimpleClassLoader` is initiating class loader for both classes but defines only the first class.